# How to access photos taken within a camera app in react native expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-camera

I made a camera app with expo camera module, I now I'm trying to have access into a specific album within this app, like it occurs with mobile native camera applications. I tried to create a function like that one, following some vague instructions I saw, but I have no idea this is the right path.

```
//trying to access photos taken through the square

const albumName = "Gryffindor";
async function seePhotos() {
  const getTakenPhotos = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
    first: 20,
    album: albumName,
    sortBy: ["creationTime"],
  });
  console.log(getTakenPhotos.assets);
  return MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync.asset.uri;
}

<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center" }}>
  <Icon name="square" size={50} color="white" onPress={seePhotos} />
</View>;
```

Comment: What do you see on the console after this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace above code with this

```
const albumName = "Gryffindor";

const seePhotos = async () => {
  try {
    const getTakenPhotos = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      first: 20,
      album: albumName,
      sortBy: MediaLibrary.SortBy.creationTime, // Should be written like this
    });
    console.log(getTakenPhotos.assets); // Check Your console
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // In case of any error
  }
};
```